# animatorset not animating views sequentially

Tags: android, animation, xamarin.android, objectanimator

I have a list of relativelayouts in my fragment. I wish to animate these views sequentially with an AnimatorSet using PlaySequentially(). I create an ObjectAnimator on each of the relativelayout's in a for loop. I want the layouts to animate up from the bottom of the fragment one after the other. At the minute only the first relativelayout is animating and iam not sure why? the rest of the layout remain still. below is my code.

```
        AnimatorSet myanimset;
        List<Animator> animlist = new List<Animator>();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {

            //resources are drawables in a list

            animatedviews[i].SetBackgroundResource(resources[i]);

            //animatedviews is a list of relativelayouts

            ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.OfFloat(animatedviews[i], "translationY", 800f, 0f);
            animator.SetDuration(2000);         
            animator.RepeatMode = ValueAnimatorRepeatMode.Restart;
            animator.RepeatCount = ValueAnimator.Infinite;
            animlist.Add(animator);     

        }

        myanimset = new AnimatorSet();
        myanimset.PlaySequentially(animlist.ToArray());
        myanimset.Start();
```

I think the code looks okay? but seen as only one layout is being animated i'am wondering if the issue is with passing my relativelayouts in a list? If anyone has greater insight into AnimatorSet and can tell me what im doing wrong id really appreciate it. Thanks!